# not able to find php.ini FPM/FastCGI

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, fpm

One of my client hosted website on digital ocean server and I want to change some values of `php.ini` file. When I check the loaded file by using `phpinfo()` the value I got is below

```
/www/server/php/74/etc/php.ini
```

but there is no such folder as `www`. Server is configured `Server API  FPM/FastCGI`.

The file under `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini` is totally different from the output I am getting using `phpinfo()`

[image]

Can anyone help me where to find the correct loaded `php.ini` file.

`Update`

The command
`readlink -f  /www/server/php/74/etc/php.ini`
is returning nothing.

While the command

```
realpath /www/server/php/74/etc/php.ini

realpath: /www/server/php/74/etc/php.ini: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I don't have the answer, but `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini` looks like the settings for `mod_php`,  which you are not using (you are using `php-fpm`). Does it need to be a server-wide change? Can't you just upload a [`.user.ini` file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) with the rest of your code?

Comment: Ok, I will create one and check.